# microsoft local report page width when table column hide

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-reporting

I create some dynamic report. by default, create a table with all available field and hidden by expression, therefore column hide when user want (by checkbox in aspx page)

problem:

1. my report is "right to left"
   therefore when hiding some column,
   report must shown from right, but as
   you know, when report render, it
   create table column from left, my
   question is how to render report
   from right ????
2. for solving this problem I create some column without data and set hidden expression != main column hidden state, therefore my problem solved but found another problem,
   report width!!! because page width really must 8.5in but when hiding some column, page Width not decrease and remain 15in! How to solve this problem?